# Post class object to RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-architecture

I have two classes:

```
public class Person {   

    private String Name;
    private Integer Age;
    private String Surname;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Animal {

    private String Name;
    private Integer Age;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the thing I wanna do - post `Animal.class` and receive response in `Person.class` format. (On the client side).

For this purpose I'm using REST Template:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Person result = restTemplate.postForObject("http://url.com", HttpMethod.POST, Animal.class, Person.class);
```

I know that passing `Animal.class` this way is not right, but I cannot set `Name` and `Age` parameters manually in this page. The main requirement to use POST method.

So what I have to do to make it work?

Comment: have you tried postForObject instead of getForObject?

Comment: Oh, my fault. I have used postForObject and copied the wrong code. Have edited this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<Animal> request = new HttpEntity<>(animal); //populated object
ResponseEntity<Person> response = restTemplate.
  exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Person.class);
```

Comment: Wow, it's a very interesting thing. Thank you for reply!
But if I want to apply this code in a function and return `Person` type value, I cannot just apply `return reponse`. How I should return it in appropriate way?

Comment: `ResponseEntity` is nothing more than a wrapper with some additional fields and the one you are looking for is the body. So you can recuperate your object, already with the correct type using `response.getBody()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped my a lot!